# Listing Microsoft Excel data on a form

Tags: excel, reference

I have a well laid out excel spreadsheet that looks something like this:

```
| NAME | SERIAL | GUN1 | OPTIC1 | OPTIC 2 |
+-----------------------------------------+
| Jonn | W0465  | MK19 | 006000 |         | 
+-----------------------------------------+
| Jimm | W1465  | MD24 |        | 455212  | 
+-----------------------------------------+
```

And I'm wanting it to be able to generate that data into another sheet that contains a form. On this form, there is 1 row per item (gun1, optic, etc.) but not everyone has the exact same equipment (Jonn has OPTIC1 while Jimm has OPTIC2, however some people may not have an optic at all).

The form will look like this (using the sample data above).

```
|  TYPE  | SERIAL | NAME |
+------------------------+
|  GUN1  |  MK19  | Jonn |
+------------------------+
| OPTIC1 | 006000 | Jonn |
+------------------------+
|  GUN1  |  MD24  | Jimm |
+------------------------+
| OPTIC2 | 455212 | Jimm |
+------------------------+
```

Any idea on how I can efficiently do this? There needs to be conditional statements and references, but I'm not sure how to effectively do all this.

I was able to successfully reference the data using `=SHEET1!$C2` etc. And I then made 2 rows for "Jonn" and everything was filled in perfectly (using absolute and relative references). However, when I selected those two rows and tried to duplicate them, it then generated rows `=SHEET1!$C4` rather than `=SHEET1!$C3` (note the C4 and C3). Since Jonn's data was two rows long on the form, the relative references would skip the 3rd row in the original excel sheet. Make sense? Please ask questions

Thanks

Comment: Are GUN1, OPTIC1 and OPTIC2 also serials? If so does that mean serial is tied to the name column (Jonn==W0456) Just a little confused by the SERIAL column in your second example table

Comment: The SERIAL column is the serial of the GUN1. They both have different guns (their GUN1 are different), and the serial numbers just go to the gun. I'm not trying to be complicated with it, just trying to get across what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So were ignoring the *SERIAL* column in table 1 (this is what confused me a little).

If you can guarantee that you will have either OPTIC1 or OPTIC2 (not both) then using worksheet functions would be possible.

If there is a possiblity that you could have BOTH then you still can do it, but you might end up with gaps in your list.

I've assumed that you can have ONE optic, not both and that row 1 on both of your sheets are used as column titles.

You can use the `ROW()` function and some maths to generate your list.

Sheet2!A2 = `=IF((ABS(ROW()/2)+1-(INT(ROW()/2)+1))=0,"GUN1",IF(INDIRECT("Sheet1!D" & (INT(ROW()/2)+1))="","OPTIC2","OPTIC1"))`

Sheet2!B2 = `=IF((ABS(ROW()/2)+1-(INT(ROW()/2)+1))=0,INDIRECT("Sheet1!C" & (INT(ROW()/2)+1)),IF(INDIRECT("Sheet1!D" & (INT(ROW()/2)+1))="",INDIRECT("Sheet1!E" & (INT(ROW()/2)+1)),INDIRECT("Sheet1!D" & (INT(ROW()/2)+1))))`

Sheet2!C2 = `=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A" & INT(ROW()/2)+1)`

These formulas should then be auto-filled down the sheet as far as required (there is no checking to see if the rows it is looking at are populated)

You might want to look into a VBA Solution as it would be much easier to maintain should you need to add extra columns or if you could have both optics.

**UPDATE**

Re-read your question and see that having NO optic is an option, which my code wont understand and leave you with some half populated rows.

You'll need to use VBA.

Comment: This is very nice! I can deal with having blank rows for the time being as I freshen up on VBA. I'll give this code a try tomorrow when I'm back at the spreadsheet and will report back!